# How can i create django models , views , forms with different names

Tags: django, django-models

Currently i have my models, views, forms in default file.
But i want to have directory structure like

```
articles
---------models
---------views
---------forms

Books
---------models
---------views
---------forms

Icecreams
---------models
---------views
---------forms
```

so that i keep separately but i don't want different app

Comment: That directory structure is easily achieved through splitting your code into apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory structure you describe is the individual apps directory structure. If you want it to look like that, you have to make them separate apps. However, you can do something like:

```
myapp/
    __init__.py
    models/
        __init__.py
        articles.py
        books.py
        icecream.py
```

Simply add a `models` directory and delete `models.py`. Then, create a separate `.py` file for each model/group of models you want to separate.

Here's the important part: on each of your models you must add the following to their `Meta` class:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        ...
        app_label = 'myapp'
```

Where 'myapp', is the main app folder all these models are stored in.

Then, edit `models/__init__.py` and import all your models there, e.g.:

```
from .articles import Article
from .books import Book
from .icecream import IceCream
```

However, the models you list as examples are pretty obvious candidates for distinct apps. The approach above is really only for related models. If your models are truly that distinct, they *should* be individual apps.

Answer (score 0):

> ... i don't want different app

But they *are* different apps, and so should be divided that way.

Comment: so basically every different class is a different app??

Comment: [Read this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301801/what-is-a-django-app-supposed-to-mean)