# Django: When to use multiple apps

Tags: python, django, web-applications

When are multiple apps actually used? I've been trying to find a concrete example of when multiple apps might be used, but haven't found anything.

I've been reading through the docs, and following the tutorial, and it says that an app has a single functionality - what does this mean? This is open to interpretation depending on the level of detail: it could refer to the individual components of a blog perhaps (ie. the menu bar, the individual blog entries, the comments section); it could refer to the pages the visitors see, and the pages writers use to create posts; it could even refer to two separate websites running within the same server.

Can someone give an example of a project which uses more the one application?

Comment: Have you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879036/django-projects-vs-apps ?

Comment: And this can help too: [What is a Django “app” supposed to mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301801/what-is-a-django-app-supposed-to-mean).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100021/django-one-app-with-many-models-vs-many-apps-with-single-model

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you have an admin and a user interface you can separate them as ;

- admin app
- user app